# How to do animation like victoria secret app homepage?

Tags: iphone

I want to try out the animation as shown in the victoria secrets application homepage.

please help me.........

Comment: can u paste a screen shot here to show that animation

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you tried any iPhone development? Did you have any problems? The code to do this isn't going to drop onto your lap from the sky...

Comment: hi i tried using tracking and decelerating property of scroll view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have done the animation which i was talking about many of u havent seen that animation so let me explain it to u in this i am having a background image and a foreground image both of them keep moving at there own speed say background image is moving a bit slow than the foreground image. This is the explanation for my question and the answer is i had used two scroll views and set there contentOffset.

Comment: Did that just happen ?!?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how to do animation in iPhone. I haven't seen the Victoria Secret App, so I don't have idea what sort animation has been done there.

There are different ways to do the animation in iPhone. You can use UIImageViews and set an animation Array or you can make some changes in the screen and use UIView class to animate the changes. I am posting links for both approach. Have a look at them.

See these two links.

http://appsamuck.com/day2.html

http://www.vellios.com/2010/07/11/simple-iphone-animation-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

Following question is in which method of `UIScrollViewDelegate` are you setting the `contentOffset` of second `scrollView` (based on first). Because if you do in `scrollViewDidScroll` or `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` then it is not a true sync. I mean it feels like second `scrollView` always lags behind the first one. We do not get the truly synced `scollViews`.